# Problem with white color in material

Tags: materials

I have problem with white color. If selected white color I got gray color.

What can be problem?

[image: er]

Comment: maybe your light isn't strong enough?

Comment: Your picture does not provide sufficient info for us to help you. Could you at least show us a full screenshot of your scene and a picture of your material setup (in the node editor)?